# Retrieve the saved WiFi passwords from Android devices

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am developing an Android application in which I need to show the saved WiFi passwords in the mobile or tablet. Like for example, if my mobile is connected to any network that n/w password is saved in my mobile. I want to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Comments helped me to some extent to find out the solution to my question. Especially  @Namik Kalavadia I am talking about you Thanks for that.
Finally here is the solution.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    File file;
    public StringBuffer ab;
    public File savefile;
    public InputStream in = null;
    public String filename = "wpa_supplicant.conf";
    public File ot_path;
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        ot_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        Log.d("aaa", ""+ot_path.toString());
    }

    public void path(View v){
        getPath();
    }
    private void getPath(){
        file = Environment.getRootDirectory();
        String ext = ".conf";
        File list[] = file.listFiles();
        ab = new StringBuffer();
        if(list!=null){
            fileNameSearch(list);

    }
    }

    public void fileNameSearch(File list[]){
        if(list!=null){
        for(int f = 0;f<list.length;f++){
            ab.append(list[f].getName()+"\n");

            File fi = list[f];
            String path = fi.getPath();
            if(fi.isDirectory()){
                fileNameSearch(fi.listFiles());
            }
            else if(path.endsWith(".conf")){
                if(path.contains(filename)){
                    try{
                    File fileForParse = copyFile(path,ot_path);
                    in = new FileInputStream(fileForParse);
                    getStringFromInputStream(in);

                Log.d("aaa", "conf I got it"+path);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
        else{
            Log.d("aaa", "List is null in method");
        }
    }
    private File copyFile(String inputPath, File outputPath) {

        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {

            if (!outputPath.exists())
            {
                outputPath.mkdirs();
            }
            savefile = new File(outputPath,filename);
            if (!savefile.exists()) {
                savefile.createNewFile();
                File f = new File(inputPath);
                Log.d("aaa",""+f.length());
                input = new FileInputStream(inputPath);        
                out = new FileOutputStream(savefile);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int read;
                while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                Log.d("aaa",""+savefile.length());
                input.close();
                input = null;
                    out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;        

            }


        }  catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
            Log.e("aaa", fnfe1.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
                catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("aaa", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
return savefile;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                if(line.contains("ssid")||line.contains("psk")){
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                if(line.contains("}")){
                    sb.append("-----------------\n");
                }

            AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
            ad.setTitle("Lis of WiFi Passwords Saved in your Mobile");
            ad.setMessage(sb);
            ad.setButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    finish();
                }
            });
            ad.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }

}
```

Comment: Not working for me in Marshmellow, Also add the write permission in the app.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are rooted, I don't know of any way to do it.  If you are rooted, or are willing to root your Galaxy for those nice guy points, you should be able to use a file manager (ASTRO, Root Browser, etc.) to find it.

Use the file manager to locate your data/misc/file folder, then look for wpa_supplicant.conf, or I assume it could be wep_supplicant.conf if his/her network is using WEP instead of WPA. Open the .conf file using a text editor (which is probably built into your file manager application, if not, add that to your shopping list). You should be able to read the password in plain text at that point.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible as far as I know . It will be a security problem if sdk tools allows to do so .

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving saved Wifi password programatically is not possible due to security issue.If you root your phone you may able to get it,but that too in an encrypted form.